# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE does not update but inserts

Tags: mysql, sql, on-duplicate-key

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(APIKEY, CLIENTID, rID) VALUES('33333meow', '2', '3')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE APIKEY='meo11111111w';
```

The above code will insert but if run a second time, the APIKEY field does not update it just inserts another row.

I've looked at documentation and it looks correct. What else am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure the combination of `clientid` and `rid` is a unique key on your table? Perhaps paste a `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: did you put a unique key on the relevant field (apikey)? No unique key = no duplicate key violations = no updates

Comment: Nope. Did not do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a unique key on your table. Probably the columns `clientid` and `rid`. That will trigger the duplicate key trigger

Comment: This did fix it. I was so used to creating tables for relationships I forgot about setting unique keys